# Angularjs filtering JSON data based on date range

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app which will displayed data from database, the app will fetch the data as json from the server.

in the form i have a checkbox and 2 `input type=date` which is one is `start date` and the other is `end date`, the checkbox will enable or disable those `input type=date`.

So i will fetch all data from database, whenever the user enable the checkbox, they will have select the date and the app will filter based on their selection, if checkbox unchecked then the app will displayed all data.

This is how i populate the data

**app.js**

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "api/Enquiry.php",
  data: {
    matcode:matcode,
    location: location,
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
}).then(function(response){
  $scope.Tablelist = response.data;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
}, function(response){
  console.log("failed");
})
```

So when the input type date is change, how can i just display the data in Tablelist according to the selected start and end date `>=startdate and <=enddate`

Is it possible to use the builtin `filterFilter`? if yes, kinda point me to the right direction.

Comment: you can just use it by importing `$filter` so you would do `.then(function (response) { $scope.Tablelist = $filter('filter')(response.data, 'your date range filter here'); } );`

Comment: any more clue? still confuse

Comment: filtering a single date won't be a problem, can't figure out to filter by date range

Comment: Just creating you an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cqzUcYR6pOj1oAJMMRr6?p=preview) is how you filter between dates, the key is the [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) you see in the docs it takes a function.

The filter function I created looks like:

```
vm.range = function (value, index, array) {
  if (value.date < new Date('2016-05-12T12:00:00Z') && value.date > new Date('2016-05-12T09:00:00Z')) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

So the value is the current object to compare, I have chosen two arbitrary dates (these can be gotten from the UI). All I do is just use the logical operators.

If you `return true` from the function then you are saying keep it. if you `return false` then you are saying nope!

This can be simplified to:

```
vm.range = function (value, index, array) {
  return (value.date < new Date('2016-05-12T12:00:00Z') && value.date > new Date('2016-05-12T09:00:00Z'));
}
```

Simple days.

Oh and UI is easy:

```
<li ng-repeat="f in vm.original | filter: vm.range">
  {{f.date}}
</li>
```

It use the pipe symbol `|` to defined the next part is going to be a filter of some kind. We use the filter filter (Yes, that is how stupid angular 1 is....) Then we just pass the `vm.range` function expression to this filter and it will be executed against each object, very similar to a `foreach`

In relation to your example of if being returned in the `$http` response, you can still do the UI the same as mine, because of `two-way` binding as soon as `$scope.Tablelist` is updated, the filter is re-run over the top. Just remember this isn't very performant for large data sets, so you may want to pull the filter into the javascript:

```
$scope.Tablelist = $filter('filter')(response.data, $scope.range);
```

Why is this more performant then in the UI. Because it doesn't cause unnecessary UI reflow till the data is filtered, I am unsure as to whether the filter does this in the UI, but I know this won't.

Comment: what will be the value of $scope.range if I am using javascript fillter