# How to use to date range filter in a report using Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie to Angular js.I had created the Report which fetched the Data from Mysqli. I just need the date range for M_Date column so that I can show the Issued bottles between two dates.

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<input type="text" ng-model="end" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">



<thead><tr>
 <th ng-click="sort('M_Date')">Date</th>
  <th>Issued Bottles </th>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:range()>
        <td>{{user.M_Date}}</td>
        <td>{{user.NoBot}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Angular js:

```
 $scope.range = function (user.M_Date, $scope.start, $scope.end) {
      return (user.M_Date < $scope.start && user.M_Date > $scope.end);
    }
```

Please suggest me some idea, So that I can code it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs filtering JSON data based on date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181121/angularjs-filtering-json-data-based-on-date-range)

Comment: @Callum, is this right .$scope.range = function (user.M_Date, $scope.start, $scope.end) {
  return (user.M_Date < $scope.start && user.M_Date > $scope.end);
}

Comment: If you omit the `$scope.start` and `$scope.end` from the function parameter list.